# Как заполнить свойства объекта из json

Tags: typescript

Получаю ошибку

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type 'A'.   No index signature with a
>   parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'A'.

пытаясь выполнить код:

```
class A {
    field1 = 1;
    field2 = '2';
}

const a: A = new A();

const b: object = {
    field2: '22',
    field3: 555
}

Object.entries(b).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) a[key] = value
});
```

Только начал изучать typescript, поэтому пока сам не очень догоняю. Я так понял нужно использовать как-то guard, используя keyof, буду очень благодарен любым советам.
[пример](https://repl.it/talk/ask/Error-string-cant-be-used-to-index-type/37262)

Comment: вопрос, какой вопрос?

Comment: интересует как получить типы или ?

Comment: Вопрос, что делать, на a[key] ругается, а как по другому организовать присвоение не знаю.

Comment: вариант первый - просто заткнуть `// @ts-irnore`, вариант второй - понять почему

Comment: (т.е. банально перевести текст ошибки)

Comment: дык... почему то понятно... вопрос как правильно

Comment: просто заткнуть, ["решение"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQGYEsCmIAmAjNALzQEDcKaWueATCdAOR1OUC+SwA9gHYQAXaAEdhjADwAVaNgAeA7LzwwE7AHwAKANbYAngC5oYXroA0Rw5ICUhnbuiYYd7ujgk1VVGAB0AC0gA8gDuvAAKAE7cAA7Y4QK62npWSFx8gkaMvNhBcBpWlKn8QgBGjMhoGDj4dIYsrKaelbQAzIYArB1InEjo3OHQGiDYQloOvNDFVoiNPEXQAG5gIIzFANpaALrQAPTb0ACi0ABKx9ABx10pAcUAVtjAAt52EBqT3r3h+2DAvon2xGpphVdtBZulFstSGs7FsKnD4Ts9ocTidzkcUhUwSNbHoXNB4jE8aVSHYjDBjPYQdx5rFfNgwHgZmkhBCVutYQjOcC9tTafTGY1MK4NKJtOYwFYpmB2YxWXCQcjTmiuskkEA) через generics ведёт к overhead и новой "ошибке"

Comment: вообще, давайте сделаем два шага назад, клиент отправил запрос и на этот запрос сервер присылает ответ. мы знаем что ждать от сервера но почему-то проводим псевдовалидацию без выброса ошибок (`hasOwnProperty`). правильно ли мы поступаем? нежно ли продолжать пихать данные если сервер прислал не то, что от него ожидали?

Comment: Спасибо, const qq = (key: any, a: A): key is keyof A =>
    a.hasOwnProperty(key); и if (qq(k, a)) a[k] = val; меня полностью устраивают.

Comment: Нужно ли пихать? Не знаю, пытаюсь делать велосипед, в виде подобия ORM, работаю в коде с доменными объектами. Во-первых с сервера приходит в снейк_кейсе, а в коде используется кемел, хочу преобразовывать, потом с сервера приходит кроме данных по одному объекту и связанные сущности, тоже собираюсь преобразовывать в виде дерева доменов. Как то так. Не подскажите, что-то в этом направлении готовое существует?

Comment: Эх, в Repl.it код стал выполнятся, а storm пишет "Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'. "

Comment: Сработал обходной вариант: if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, key)) (a as any)[key] = value. Ничего более умного не заходит, чувствую в ts себя пока полным лошарой.

Comment: повторюсь - правильный вариант - просто заткнуть используя `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: может быть интересно - https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm#extensions

Comment: TypeORM, насколько я понял предназначен для работы на сервере? Т.е. замена ларавела (который я использую). Я же в коде на вью пытаюсь создать доменные объекты. Они под капотом обращаются через рест на сервер (ларавел), но позволяют работать не с сырыми данными, а типизированными объектами.

Comment: к стати! из нового: `// @ts-expect-error`

Comment: не знаю как сейчас, раньше поддержка ТС отсутствовала в VUE. вы же знаете про ЧАТ - https://chat.vuejs.org/ ДОКА - https://ru.vuejs.org/ и ПЛАГИН ДЛЯ VSCODE ? (нуу, мало ли)

Comment: ах, да, [tag:vue] таг можете попробовать использовать в вопросе, 250 отслеживающих всё же

Comment: забыл написать, TypeOrm может работать в браузере

Comment: Насчет TypeOrm может работать в браузере, спасибо, буду изучать вопрос. Вью с ТС без проблем, а грядущая третья версия будет изначально ориентирована на его использование.